Markdown_V2 support for update.message.reply_text
edit: as for importing question: from telegram.constants import ParseMode
I have this code below, everything works otherwise if I remove the parse_mode bit (besides bold etc):
await update.message.reply_text(await main_menu_message(), reply_markup=await main_menu_keyboard(), parse_mode=telegram.constants.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
and have imported everything - here is the error I get back:
await update.message.reply_text(await main_menu_message(), reply_markup=await main_menu_keyboard(), parse_mode=telegram.constants.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2) NameError: name 'telegram' is not defined
I've been stuck on this for hours and have explored mostly every other post to no avail. Thank you and let me know if I need to give any more info.
I've tried entering it as a string, using just MARKDOWN_V2 and other entries like it
edit 2:
Okay just tried updating to parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2 and get the error : telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character '(' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'
And here is my message function:
async def main_menu_message(): return "Bot Demo *bold* \n(for trial purposes only)\n~~---------------~~\n\n[Link Text](http://example.com)"

How are you importing ParseMode? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code you're having issues with (as formatted text, no images please!).

Refer to the examples from the documentation, you're likely not importing or using ParseMode correctly.

Just added it in :) and wow, fast reply thank you!
Edit 2: just saw the second comment let me try that!

Okay just tried updating to parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2 and get the error : telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character '(' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\' 

Because you're importing ParseMode, you can reference it by just calling ParseMode directly. You don't need to (and shouldn't) call it with the full import path.
So in your example,
parse_mode=telegram.constants.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2

becomes
parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2


Out of curiosity, what IDE are you using? I would have thought any modern linter would be able to catch this.

Okay just tried updating to parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2 and get the error : telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character '(' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'
Currently using VS Code, don't think its considered an IDE
Sorry for the mess, just updated my original question!

Okay partially got it working, thank you!
